# Docker run - User group not working as expected?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker, user-permissions, usergroups

I have a script that communicates over serial port (`/dev/ttyUSB0`). I want to run it from within a Docker image. However I don't seem to have permissions to do it from within the image. I follow these steps:

On my host, if I run `ln -l /dev/ttyUSB0` I get:

```
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 188, 0 jul  2 14:34 /dev/ttyUSB0
```

Good, it means that in order to read/write to it, I need to be either `root`, or part of the `dialout` group.

I become member of this group in my host:

```
$ sudo usermod -aG dialout $(whoami)
```

Then I log out and log in again to make this effective.

After that, I verify that I can communicate perfectly with `/dev/ttyUSB0` from my host. However if I run the docker image:

```
docker run --user=1000:1000 --rm=true --tty=true --privileged=true --device=/dev/ttyUSB0 --volume=<my_dir>:<my_dir> --workdir=<my_dir> <my_docker_image> <my_script>
```

Then it complains:

```
can't open device "/dev/ttyUSB0": Permission denied
```

However if I use: `--user=1000:20`, then it works fine. The group `20` is the `dialout` group.

Now my question:

**Why does Docker not understand that my user (1000) and group (1000) is part of the `dialout` group?**

This was working when I used the *old* docker (`apt-get install docker-io, docker-engine`), but after updating to the new `Docker CE` this stopped working.

**Setup**:

- Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS Kernel 4.4.0-83-generic.
- Docker version: Docker version 17.06.0-ce, build 02c1d87.

Thanks!

Comment: From inside the container, your processes won't be able to see your host tc's user and group information. This is because the container will have its own /etc/passwd and /etc/group files, which may not match what your host has.

Comment: Thanks! I also tried mounting those files with the `--volume` option, but it didn't work either.

The solution was to pass `--group-add=dialout` to the `docker run` call

Answer (score 2):

As stated in a comment, The solution was to pass `--group-add=dialout` to the docker run call. However, be aware that when using docker images that provides a way to specify the user and group using an environment variable  (usually `-e PUID=<UID> -e PGID=<GID>`) **it overwrites that setting**.